# listview with 4 textview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, adapter

i must create a listview where the single row have 4 textview.
My problem is that I don't understand how can I use the adapter,so someone can help me with the adapter and its implementation?

this is my layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >




<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="192dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:text="Grazie per aver parcheggiato da noi!"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/mylist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
</ListView>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnEsci"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Torna a scelta" />

</LinearLayout>
```

this is the single row(single_feed)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <!-- TEXT OF FEED -->

 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Numero macchina: #"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTarga"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Targa: #"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtOra"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ora ingresso: #"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCosto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Prezzo uscita: #"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
        android:lines="1" 
        />
```

this is my adapter:

```
public class MioAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private final Context context;
        private final String[] values;

        public MioAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
            super(context, R.layout.single_feed, values);
            this.context = context;
            this.values = values;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_feed, parent, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            textView.setText(values[position]);
            // Change the icon for Windows and iPhone


            return rowView;
        }
```

and finally this is my activity:

```
public class checkout extends Activity{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //apro la view
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.checkout);

        //gestsco l'adapter per creare la lista
        public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                    "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                    "Linux", "OS/2" };
            MioAdapter adapter = new MioAdapter(this, values);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
};
```

Someone can help me with the adapter? 
thanks to all that can help me in this easy trouble :)

Comment: Tip: every listview should have `height` as `fill_parent`

Comment: Do you want to have 4 columns (TextViews next to each other)?

Answer (score 1):

[See this Custom listView](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-customized-listview.html)

And there is two textviews in row and you just add four textview so add in row layout file.And add In textview `android:maxLines="1"` for single line textview.

Answer (score 1):

For single row(single_feed):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

Also keep the layout_width fixed for all the text views, so that they may fit in single line.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add 4 Textviews in single_feed.xml Layout. That will be layout for your listitem
2. find id of all the textviews in the getview of MioAdapter
3. Maintain index in the adapter by taking an int as instance variable.
4. assign text in the getView

Answer (score 0):

First there is something wrong somewhere. If you want a ListView you need a list of elements (one element, one row).

So if you want multiple TextViews per row you will need multiple values per element. So you will need an array of array for example.

You can also try the SimpleCursorAdapter. You build a MatrixCursor with your data: `MatrixCursor mc = new MatrixCursor(your_column_names);` and add elements (one for each row): `mc.addRow(row_values);`  (where `your_column_names` and `row_values` are of type `String[]`)

Then you use a SimpleCursorAdapter, where `String[] from = your_column_values` and `int[] to = your_TextView_ids` (ids from single_feed.xml)

Comment: no, I don't need an array of array beacause my information is ordered,so I know what will see in every textview